# jQuery mobile theme "scope" -- not an option, or buried somewhere I don't see?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

When you're downloading a [jQuery UI theme,](http://jqueryui.com/download/) you can define a "CSS Scope".

[image: Screeenshot showing jQuery UI theme CSS Scope option]

If you enter, e.g., #my-app in the CSS Scope, then all the CSS rules will be prepended with #my-app, limiting the scope of those rules to the element with id `my-app`.

This is very useful, and I was hoping to accomplish the same thing with a jQuery mobile theme, but I don't see this option anywhere on the [jQuery mobile download page](http://jquerymobile.com/download/), nor on the [jQuery mobile themeroller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/).

Does no such feature exist with jQuery mobile, or am I just missing the location of this option?

Comment: It doesn't look like it does, probably because theme roller is a complete JQM style customizer with 3 different themes to add. You will need to create your own custom CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran through the [jQuery Mobile Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/), selecting only the widgets I was actually using, and while it didn't produced a "scoped" CSS file, it produced a different CSS file that didn't alter other elements of my page. This was the solution in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Scope is easy to achieve. It would have been nice if they supported it. But here's what you can do. 
Download the uncompressed version. Then add your scope front of every selector.

```
#MySchope .jquerySelectors {...
```

You will need to use Notepad++ or any other text editors to replace them automatically. You will will have to look for the beginning of the line and for the first character to be either # or .

For exmaple

```
 if \r\n.    find and replace \r\n#MyScope .
 if \r\n#    find and replace \r\n#MyScope #
```

With these two clicks conditions, you will achieve a scoped jquerymobile theme.

Good Luck

Comment: This works, if the source document is formatted appropriately and doesn't have any selectors that match elements outside your "host element." Unfortunately, jQuery Mobile's CSS file has rules that match on body.classname, and obviously if you prefix that with div#my-host-element-id, it's going to break the rule. Bummer.

Comment: You are Correct. Still my solution will only replace the classes and ids (. and #). So if there are selectors for div's or body tags, then they will have to be manually overridden.

Comment: Unfortunately in jQuery Mobile's CSS, it doesn't actually specify `body.classname`, just `.classname`, and some of those classnames are applied to the `body` element. Either way, you have to manually go through and update the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this from the jquery mobile theme roller or anywhere else, but it can also be done via your task runner.

For example i use GULP and used the gulp-scope-css gulp plugin to scope the jquery mobile structure css ( as as a source i used the jquery-mobile css without theme uncompressed )

I added a task in my gulp file :

```
gulp.task('scope', function() {
gulp.src("oursin/mobile/js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css")
    . pipe( scopeCss( "#ifra" ) )
    . pipe( gulp . dest("./dist") ) ;
});
```